# Monitor every battery state change even with screen off

Tags: android

I want my app to monitor every percent change and be able to execute some code when it changes even when the screen is off.

Yes, I know this is a bad idea and will drain battery unnecessarily. I am giving the user the option to turn this off. Also, this is more of an experiment at this point than a user-friendly feature. So please do not answer that I should not monitor every change.

I also know this is possible because Tasker implements this quite well. You can set a profile to do something on "Battery Changed" and it works when the screen is off. How is Tasker doing this?

From my research I have found that I will probably need to use AlarmManager and a partial wake lock from the PowerManager class. However I don't know how to best use these classes. Should I set an alarm manager to check every minute for a change? Tasker seems to not eat up too much battery when doing this so I would like to keep that in mind.

I have this working when the screen is on just fine. I have a service that registers an ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED intent filter and a receiver to implement my code that I want to run. However when the screen is off, the code does not run until I "wake" the device by turning on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is Tasker doing this?

You would have to ask the developers of Tasker.

> Should I set an alarm manager to check every minute for a change?

It would not need to be nearly that frequent. You can only get battery charge levels in integer percentages, at best. Checking every 5-10 minutes is probably more than sufficient. You could also consider:

- Letting users control the polling frequency
- Implementing a learning algorithm that tries to determine a good polling interval based upon how the device has behaved previously

> I have a service that registers an ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED intent filter and a receiver to implement my code that I want to run.

Yuck. There is no added value for you tying up memory waiting for the battery level to tick over.

You can get the current battery level by calling `registerReceiver()` with an `IntentFilter` for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` and a `null` `BroadcastReceiver`. `registerReceiver()` will return the last `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` broadcast that went out. Hence, again, a polling mechanism should be just fine.

Comment: Thank you for your response, for practicality I am going to use a polling method. But I'm still curious how to monitor every ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED while the phone is asleep without polling. Any thoughts?

Comment: @TheDrizzle: Don't let the device go to sleep. The device will not wake up on its own to tell you that the battery lost a little charge. This, of course, is really bad for the battery.

Comment: Well there has to be another way since Tasker is doing it. Could it possible require root? I was experimenting and I added a partial wake lock to my ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED receiver's onReceive method and so far it does what I'm wanting except it seems to trigger every second or so at the moment.

Comment: @TheDrizzle: "Well there has to be another way since Tasker is doing it" -- they are probably polling.

Comment: Perhaps. But in my testing it seems to send the message as soon as the battery ticks over.

Comment: @TheDrizzle: By definition, if the device is asleep, you do not know when the battery ticks over. Hence, your testing is keeping the device awake, and regular monitoring of `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` can take effect.

Comment: I see your point. In my testing the device has been sleeping, but there is not a good way to test exactly when the battery ticked over. When you receive the message from Tasker the battery has indeed changed, but you don't know how long it had changed before tasker noticed this. Also, I have many applications that use a partial wake lock on my phone thus making an accurate test even harder. I wish I could just look at the Tasker source code :(